# How to check whether the "User" has a confirmed E-mail inside ASP.NET Identity (Web Forms)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, asp.net-identity

On my login page I want to implement a system, whereby if the user exists but doesn't have a confirmed email (`IsEmailConfirmed`), the user needs to verify/confirm the email.

I don't have any problem re-sending the confirmation code, my issue is where to put the statement and how make sure the users enter the correct username and password (Users should be valid).

### Login (Code Behind)

```
protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Validate the user password
  var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
  var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

  // Require the user to have a confirmed email before they can log on.
  var user = manager.FindByName(username.Text);

  if (IsValid)
   {
    if (user != null)
     {
      // This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
      // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
      var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(username.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: true);

      switch (result)
       {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], 
                                                           Response);
        break;

        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
         //Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");    
         FailureText.Text = "This account has been locked out, please try again later.";
         ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
         return;

        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
          Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
          Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
          RememberMe.Checked),
          true);
          break;

         case SignInStatus.Failure:
         default:
          FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt";
          ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
          break;    
          }   
        }
      }    
  else
  {
     FailureText.Text = "Account not found.";
     ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
  }

  //else if (IsValid & !manager.IsEmailConfirmed(user.Id))
  //{
     //    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "LaunchServerSide", "$(function() { OpenLoginModal(); });", true);
        //    LoginModalTitle.Text = "Account Verification".ToUpper();
        //    LoginModalDetails.Text = "You must have a confirmed email account.";
        //    //ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
        //    //ResendConfirm.Visible = true;
        //}
 }
```

I appreciate your efforts in reaching a solution for my problem

Comment: if it is inside an `if-else` statement it doesn't matter where you put it as long as it has the requirements specified. And for the user to have the correct `username` and `password` this is the basics of the login. You need to verify it if it exists any users with those credentials. P.s. skipped a bit of your question there that's why i deleted my comment.

Comment: You're right. I've already tried that but when the user enters an invalid password instead of showing "Invalid login attempt" it actually runs my email verification statement.

Comment: that's becuase you check only if the user exists and not if the credentials are the correct ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correct: You want to make sure that both username and password is correct before we check if account is active?

```
protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    var user = manager.FindByName(username.Text);

    if (IsValid)
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(username.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: true);

            // If username and password is correct check if account is activated.
            if(!user.EmailConfirmed && result == SignInStatus.Success)
            {
                FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt. You must have a confirmed email account.";
                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                return;
            }        

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], 
                                                           Response);
                    break;
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    //Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");    
                    FailureText.Text = "This account has been locked out, please try again later.";
                    ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                    return;

                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                                                    Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
                                                    RememberMe.Checked),
                                                    true);
                    break;
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt";
                    ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                    break;    
            }                
        }    
        else
        {
            FailureText.Text = "Account not found.";
            ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you verrryyyyyyyyy much Joachim :)

Answer (score 2):

A slight modification is needed to check if the user is confirmed. You need to check the `IsEmailConfirmed` property to see if the user has confirmed the account or not.

[This article](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/security/create-a-secure-aspnet-web-forms-app-with-user-registration,-email-confirmation-and-password-reset) explains the flow and how to perform these actions pretty nicely. Snippet below is snatched from that article.

```
    var user = manager.FindByName(Email.Text);
    if (user != null)
    {
        if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
        {
            FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt. You must have a confirmed email address. Enter your email and password, then press 'Resend Confirmation'.";
            ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            ResendConfirm.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
             // your other logic goes here if the user is confirmed.
             ....
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // user does not exist.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it's the same scenario that without the correct password user can see that message.

Comment: When the user is not confirmed also log the user out again.

Answer (score 0):

in .NET 7 Login.cshtml.cs

```
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            if (result.IsNotAllowed)
            {
                var user = _signInManager.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    if (!user.Result.EmailConfirmed)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Account isn't active, Get Your Email & click on Active link, ");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "incorrect username or password");//Email not found
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "incorrect username or password");
                return Page();
            }
```

Comment: When the user is not confirmed it will get an error but is logged in.

Also call await _signInManager.SignOutAsync(); to signe the user out again.